# Get absolute media path programatically in hybris

Tags: url, media, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working on Hybris Version 5.4.0, and specifically on a Job exporting my datas. I would like the full external path (i.e. the URL) of my media to be exported instead of the relative path

Ex:  /medias/sys_master/h76/hd6/8865465963102.jpg --> http://myserver:myport/medias/sys_master/h76/hd6/8865465963102.jpg

I've seen ways to do it in Hybris Wiki using static declarations in locale, but I would like to programatically do it, as my app could be run on various servers and environments.

I've already tried common ways to get server address in Java (for example using INet) but it didn't work.

Finally, I've seen that in HMC, the exact information I want is displayed at the end here :

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2013 hybris AG - hybris   
Version:    null
    5.4.0.0
    Last compile: 20180410 1543
    Release date: 20141113 1921
Server: localhost:9101
Locale: English (United Kingdom) - en_GB
Timezone:   Central European Time - Europe/Paris
```

but it's catching a servlet request in defaultContent_jsp.java (then `out.print(request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort());`), do I have a way to spread this information to my Jobs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Configure media URL in property file

change `mycmssite` and `mysite` with your respective value

```
media.mycmssite.http=https\://www.mysite.com
media.mycmssite.https=https\://www.mysite.com
```

### Get MediaUrlForSite in your job

- Get current session site
- Get getMediaUrlForSite
- Concate getMediaUrlForSite and mediaURL

---

```
@Resource(name = "cmsSiteService")
private CMSSiteService cmsSiteService;

@Resource(name = "siteBaseUrlResolutionService")
private SiteBaseUrlResolutionService siteBaseUrlResolutionService;

MediaModel media = ...
final CMSSiteModel currentSite = cmsSiteService.getCurrentSite();

final String mediaUrlForSite = siteBaseUrlResolutionService.getMediaUrlForSite(currentSite, true, "");

String downloadURL = mediaUrlForSite + media .getURL()
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly answering my question as I have to change config file for each server I'm using. Nevertheless, I didn't find other ways to do so, therefore I ended up implementing your solution with installation instructions, and it's working greatly, so thank you for your time and your help !

Comment: I didn't understand your use-case. Why did you not want to change config file? When you say  `I have to change config file for each server I'm using`, are you talking about different Hybris setup (DEV, QA, UAT etc) or multiple cluster nodes?